# EF Core Many-to-Many self join

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to describe a many-to-many self-referential relationship to Entity Framework Core 2.  Essentially what I'm trying to model is a sort of tree structure, in which each element can have an arbitrary number of parent and child elements (so I guess more a graph than a tree).  Here's what I have so far:

```
public class OrgLevel
{
    ...

    public ICollection<OrgLevelOrgLevels> OrgLevelOrgLevelsAsParent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrgLevelOrgLevels> OrgLevelOrgLevelsAsChild { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrgLevel> ParentOrganizationStructureLevels { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrgLevel> ChildOrganizationStructureLevels { get; set; }
}

public class OrgLevelOrgLevels
{
    public OrgLevel ParentOrgLevel { get; set; }
    public OrgLevel ChildOrgLevel { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
{
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.ParentOrgLevel, t.ChildOrgLevel });

        builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>().HasOne(olol => olol.ChildOrgLevel)
            .WithMany(col => col.OrgLevelOrgLevelsAsChild);

        builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>().HasOne(olol => olol.ParentOrgLevel)
            .WithMany(pol => pol.OrgLevelOrgLevelsAsParent);
    }
}
```

When i try to generate the initial migration, i get the following:

`The navigation property 'ChildOrgLevel' cannot be added to the entity type 'OrgLevelOrgLevels' because a property with the same name already exists on entity type 'OrgLevelOrgLevels'.`

I am assuming this means that for the join table, it's trying to name both columns the same thing as they reference the same table.

Additionally, I don't really have any idea how to wire the last two navigation properties in the `OrgLevel` model so that they will use the join table to resolve.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the purpose of the `ParentOrganizationStructureLevels` and `ChildOrganizationStructureLevels` collections. They are not causing your current issue, but will cause other issues when you resolve it.

Comment: What I intended here is for these to represent the actual entities that the join table is mapping.  I'd like to be able to traverse the relationship through the join table and get the children or parents for a given OrgLevel.  Perhaps this isn't possible with EF Core.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a mixture of many-to-many with explicit junction table and implicit junction table (not supported in EF Core yet). When supported, you can use one or the another, but not both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue is the following fluent configuration:

```
builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.ParentOrgLevel, t.ChildOrgLevel });
```

The error message is kind of misleading. This overload expects *primitive* properties (either explicit or [shadow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties)), but you are passing [navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties).

There are several ways to resolve it.

First, add explicit FK properties to the model (assuming referenced PK property type is `int`):

```
public class OrgLevelOrgLevels
{
    public int ParentOrgLevelId { get; set; }
    public OrgLevel ParentOrgLevel { get; set; }
    public int ChildOrgLevelId { get; set; }
    public OrgLevel ChildOrgLevel { get; set; }
}
```

and use

```
builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>()
    .HasKey(t => new { t.ParentOrgLevelId, t.ChildOrgLevelId });
```

Another way is to keep the model as is, but use another `HasKey` overload and pass shadow property names *after* they are defined:

```
builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>().HasOne(olol => olol.ChildOrgLevel)
    .WithMany(col => col.OrgLevelOrgLevelsAsChild)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>().HasOne(olol => olol.ParentOrgLevel)
    .WithMany(pol => pol.OrgLevelOrgLevelsAsParent);

builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>()
     .HasKey("ParentOrgLevelId", "ChildOrgLevelId");
```

Of course you can define them explicitly in advance:

```
builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>()
    .Property<int>("ParentOrgLevelId");

builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>()
    .Property<int>("ChildOrgLevelId");

builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>()
     .HasKey("ParentOrgLevelId", "ChildOrgLevelId");

builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>().HasOne(olol => olol.ChildOrgLevel)
    .WithMany(col => col.OrgLevelOrgLevelsAsChild)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

builder.Entity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>().HasOne(olol => olol.ParentOrgLevel)
    .WithMany(pol => pol.OrgLevelOrgLevelsAsParent);
```

Note that this model introduces multiple cascade paths, so you need to turn cascade delete off at least of one of the two relationships and handle it manually.

Comment: This is working.  Thanks for the extra tip on cascade behavior!

Comment: Your solution is working fine for OrgLevelOrgLevelsAsChild and OrgLevelOrgLevelsAsParent mapping. However, the mapping of 
ParentOrganizationStructureLevels and ChildOrganizationStructureLevels is missing. Please let us know who to write the mapping for ParentOrganizationStructureLevels and ChildOrganizationStructureLevels.

Comment: @AdeelAhmed Take a look at the comments under the question. It was not possible to have the two collections you are asking for at that time (EF Core 2.x), hence no mapping. Nowadays (EF Core 5+) it is possible, and all you need (in addition of the above) I guess is to associate the join entity, e.g. `builder.Entity<OrgLevel>().HasMany(e => e.ParentOrganizationStructureLevels).WithMany(e => e.ChildOrganizationStructureLevels).UsingEntity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>();`

Comment: Thanks Ivan. We have tried your proposed solution.

builder.Entity<OrgLevel>().HasMany(e => e.ParentOrganizationStructureLevels).WithMany(e => e.ChildOrganizationStructureLevels).UsingEntity<OrgLevelOrgLevels>();

However, it is still not mapping ParentOrganizationStructureLevels and ChildOrganizationStructureLevels lists. Is there any way we can specify the parentId and childId in the mapping ?

Comment: @AdeelAhmed It's hard to answer/provide solutions in the comments. Please either take a look at [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration), there is an example of configuring such relationships having both normal and skip navigation collections, or post own question. I believe the example should be enough, everything is configured with single `UsingEntity` call.

Comment: Thanks Ivan for your response. Issue has been resolved using UsingEnitity<> overload configureLeft and configureRight.